# WAMP - phpmyadmin 403 error from localhost, but not from IP 127.0.0.1?

Tags: windows, localhost

I was wondering if anyone can explain this to me.

I installed WAMP 2.2.  I opened up the dashboard menu, and clicked localhost.  I was brought to the WAMP localhost home page.  I clicked on phpmyadmin and get a 403 access is denied error message.  However, if I type in the ip address 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin in the address bar, then VOILA, I am in (however, I am not prompted to login to phpmyadmin, I am instantly brought to the phpmyadmin homepage)

Please note, I have found the solution to get rid of the 403 error message when entering phpmyadmin from the the localhost extension (change the Deny all setting to Allow all); so I am not asking how to solve that, but my question is:

Why if localhost and 127.0.0.1 go to the same spot, will when using the IP addres, I am granted access to subsequent applications and with localhost I am not?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug present with the WAMP. Remove all other instance of 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, because each time you installed WAMP, 127.0.0.1 will be added. ALso, remove or # ::1 if IPv6 support is present. Now restart the WAMP and give it 1 minutes and check it again. I have atleast tested it 5 times and all the times its work.

Comment: +1: check your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have in `/etc/hosts` something like `127.0.1.1 localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1 localhost` as it happens frequently and mysql is listening only 127.0.0.1